# What is computational complexity of toString method of an object of TreeSet class

Tags: java, complexity-theory

I was thinking, since it is a tree and it must traverse it all in sorted order, then it means the algorithm goes log(n) n times, making complexity n log(n). Am I right??

i asked someone and they couldn't respond, i also googled and didn't find answer

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759256/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-treeset-iteration. Since you can implement toString with a single iteration, it is also O(n).

Comment: yeah hurry to tag this question duplicate. great job.

Comment: I wouldn't argue that this is definitely a duplicate, but let me know if my comment does not answer the question sufficiently.